# facebook User request limit reached

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are getting the below issue when querying facebook graph API

**(#17) User request limit reached**

i know that this is a throttling error on user level rate limiting as mentioned in the below link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting

But we  were never facing the issue before, suddenly this issue has started coming, Did facebook changed the rate limits recently ?

does anybody have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

AS Per doc:
Your app can make 200 calls per hour per user in aggregate. As an example, if your app has 100 users, this means that your app can make 20,000 calls. This isn't a per-user limit, so one user could make 19,000 of those calls and another could make 1,000. This limit is calculated based on the number of calls made in the previous hour.

The number of users for your app is calculated as the average number of daily active users plus today's new logins

Not all API calls are subject to rate limits so the number of calls you make may not match what you see in the rate limit tool. Facebook also throttles calls based on CPU time used and total time. It is difficult to hit these limits, so it is an extremely rare occurrence. This information is exposed in the detail pane for each sample. Click on the graph in the rate limit tool on your dashboard for details.

Recommendations:
Rate limiting defines limits on how many API calls can be made within a specified time period. When a rate limit is exceeded, all API calls from an app are throttled and fail for a brief period of time. Once an app is throttled, the caller will get an error for subsequent calls with error code = 4, CodedException. It can take up to an hour for your requests to be accepted again.

To avoid rate limiting:
Spread out queries evenly between two time intervals to avoid sending traffic in spikes. Use filters to limit the data response size and avoiding calls that request overlapping data. Use the rate limiting header to dynamically balance your call volume.

Answer (score -1):

You called API too many times (working too hard, huh?). This is how Facebook calculates the Limit. ref: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting/)